# Standards for continuation sheets (letterhead templates)

Tags: page-layout, template-design, microsoft-office, microsoft-word

I've only ever designed a couple of letterhead templates throughout my design career so far, and neither of them required continuation sheets.

The front page of the one that I'm designing, has the company logo + contact details in the header, and then the company registration number + address in the footer.

I'm wondering what the standard approach is for the *footer* for the continuation sheet... should this contain the address like the front page? Or should I leave it blank?

As for the header of the continuation sheet, this uses a graphic device taken from the logo (without the contact details that are on the front).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuation sheets which I've worked on have primarily only had a reduced header, like the one you describe, and no footer at all. It depends on what the client wants, but I wouldn't be opposed to a discreet footer with just the address and phone (in case the pages get separated). You don't need *all* the information from the front page, but some information isn't a bad thing. It's not required, however.